# Integrating MSAL into Jetpack Compose using Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-ad-msal, koin

Using Koin for dependency injection, I'm trying to integrate Microsoft Authentication Library into my Jetpack Compose Android project.

For the first step I've created a class named AuthHelper to handle the auth process

```kotlin
class AuthHelper(private val publicClientApplication: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication) {
    fun authenticate(): Flow<Boolean> = flow {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Perform the authentication logic
            //publicClientApplication.signIn(...)
        }
    }
}
```

And a ViewModel to consume it

```kotlin
class AuthViewModel(private val authHelper: AuthHelper) : ViewModel() {
    fun authenticate(): Flow<Boolean> {
        return authHelper.authenticate()
    }
}
```

And here's my Application Class

```kotlin
class App : Application() {
    private val modules = module {
        scope<MainActivity> {
            scoped {
                PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(get<MainActivity>(), R.raw.auth_config_single_account)
            }
        }

        single { AuthHelper(get()) }

        viewModel { AuthViewModel(get()) }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@App)
            modules(modules)
        }
    }
}
```

`R.raw.auth_config_single_account` is the json created in the Azure console, and stored as Raw into the res folder.

When I run this code, the error I got is

`Instance creation error : could not create instance for '[Singleton:'com.example.tooling.AuthHelper']': org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication' q:''. Check your definitions!`

As If the first module, the one I use to initialize the PublicClientApplication is completely ignored.

Any help is really appreciated, even using other way than the one described here. Is a new project, and I can change anything I want. I've just used the tool I'm familiar with.

Comment: Hi @Valerio, if you have a working solution, I'm glad to see it, I have exactly the same need

Comment: @Turvy you should use 
`val pca PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(applicationContext, R.raw.auth_config_single_account)` and then create the params, IE:
`  val params = SignInParameters.builder().withActivity(activity).withScopes(scopes).withCallback(object : AuthenticationCallback { ... })`
Depending on your implementation you should pass context as koin context to the singleton cointaining the code above (if you're using the singleton way)

Comment: thanks, I found also a similar project to help me ```https://github.com/v-po/msal-sample```